# Can you decrease Analytics's view permission to only one segment?

Tags: google-analytics, permissions, analytics, segment

I have a business and a lot of costumers sell they're products on my site. And now i want to give a permission to some of them to see and analyze the data of their products.

Can i give them a view permission for only one page or for only one segment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a new View and set up filters as you need.

See GA support about filters:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823?hl=en